# How to Load Emacs Configuration File in LISPBOX

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, configuration-files, dotfiles

I am currently using Lisp in a Box which comes pre-configured to not load the ".emacs" configuration file.  I would like to change the shortcut so that Emacs does load this file by default but I cannot find where this piece of code is.

Can someone please help me locate this and if possible tell me which bits of code to remove/edit to allow this file to be loaded?  I am using Lispbox on OS X if that makes any difference.

As far as I know I am looking for one of the following pieces of code for not loading an init file:
-q
--no-init-file
--no-site-file

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW, setting up Emacs, SLIME and Common Lisp on OS X isn't all that hard, and you might find it a bit easier to manage.

Answer (score 1):

It's inside Lispbox.sh (Linux) or Lispbox.bat (Windows).

```
%EMACS% --no-init-file --no-site-file --eval=%TO_EVAL%
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally the init files loaded are either `~/.emacs.d/init.el` or if that is not present `~/.emacs` so, maybe you can get an indication of what is going on in the first file?

Also, the buffer `*Messages*` will sometimes tell you a bit about what is going on.

Comment: Thanks,

Finally had a breakthrough and after a ton of searching I managed to find what I was looking for.

For anyone else looking to do the same the file that you need to edit is:
"/Emacs/Contents/MacOS/lispbox.sh"

Then remove "--no-init-file --no-site-file " from the last line of code to allow .emacs to load on starting Lispbox. :)

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of problems (binary tries to load some unknown configuration file) you can analyze using the tool 'strace'.

Answer (score 0):

just simple and obvious way.
inside lispbox.sh just insert into (progn (load "lispbox") (slime))   (load "~/emacs") or where is you .emacs file.

form

```
exec ${LISPBOX_HOME}/emacs-23.2/bin/emacs --no-init-file --no-site-file --eval='(progn (load "lispbox") (slime))'
```

make

```
exec ${LISPBOX_HOME}/emacs-23.2/bin/emacs --no-init-file --no-site-file --eval='(progn (load "lispbox") (load "~/.emacs") (slime))'
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to solve the same problem, and I found the answer.

First, I opened my lispbox.bat file.

```
@echo off
rem Thanks to Venkat who provided this bit of COMMAND wizardry.

if NOT %OS%==Windows_NT goto checkhome
for %%i in ( "%CD%" ) do set LISPBOX_HOME=%%~si%
goto start

:checkhome

rem
rem if the environment variable is not defined, dereferencing
rem it produces the same string!
rem

if %LISPBOX_HOME%==%LISPBOX_HOME% goto noenv
:start

set EMACS=%LISPBOX_HOME%/emacs-23.2/bin/runemacs.exe
set TO_EVAL="(progn (load \"lispbox\") (slime))"

%EMACS%  --no-init-file --no-site-file --eval=%TO_EVAL%

goto end

:noenv

echo LISPBOX_HOME environment variable should be set and
echo point to the installation directory of LISPBOX before
echo launching this command.

:end
```

Next, I modified some lines in it.

From

```
set EMACS=%LISPBOX_HOME%/emacs-23.2/bin/runemacs.exe
set TO_EVAL="(progn (load \"lispbox\") (slime))"

%EMACS% --no-init-file --no-site-file --eval=%TO_EVAL%
```

TO  (Just deleting "--no-init-file")

```
set EMACS=%LISPBOX_HOME%/emacs-23.2/bin/runemacs.exe
set TO_EVAL="(progn (load \"lispbox\") (slime))"

%EMACS% --no-site-file --eval=%TO_EVAL%
```